# lazy function definitions in scala

Tags: scala, design-patterns, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization

I've been learning scala and I gotta say that it's a really cool language. I especially like its pattern matching capabilities and function literals but I come from a javascript, ruby background and one of my favorite patterns in those languages is the lazy function and method definition pattern. An example in javascript is

```
var foo = function() {
  var t = new Date();
  foo = function() {
    return t;
  };
  return foo();
};
```

The same code with minor tweaks works in ruby where you just use the singleton object to redefine the method after the computation is performed. This kind of thing comes in really handy when expensive computation are involved and you don't know ahead of time if you are going to need the result. I know that in scala I can use a cache to simulate the same kind of result but I'm trying to avoid conditional checks and so far my experiments have returned negative results. Does anyone know if there is a lazy function or method definition pattern in scala?

Note: The javascript code is from Peter Michaux's [site](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/lazy-function-definition-pattern).

Comment: Remember, unless no on really did answer your question, you should give one of the answers the pretty green check mark!

Comment: +1 for the link to the extremely interesting article on Peter Michaux's site. :-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

All that complicated code in JavaScript appears to just try to cache the value of the date.  In Scala, you can achieve the same thing trivially:

```
lazy val foo = new Date
```

And, if don't even want to make a val, but want to call a function that will only execute the expensive code if it needs it, you can

```
def maybeExpensive(doIt: Boolean, expensive: => String) {
  if (doIt) println(expensive)
}
maybeExpensive(false, (0 to 1000000).toString)  // (0 to 1000000).toString is never called!
maybeExpensive(true, (0 to 10).toString)        // It is called and used this time
```

where the pattern `expensive: => String` is called a by-name parameter, which you can think of as, "Give me something that will generate a string on request."  Note that if you use it twice, it will regenerate it each time, which is where Randall Schultz' handy pattern comes in:

```
def maybeExpensiveTwice(doIt: Boolean, expensive: => String) {
  lazy val e = expensive
  if (doIt) {
    println(e)
    println("Wow, that was " + e.length + " characters long!")
  }
}
```

Now you generate only if you need it (via the by-name parameter) *and* store it and re-use it if you need it again (via the lazy val).

So do it this way, not the JavaScript way, even though you *could* make Scala look a lot like the JavaScript.

Comment: I was just trying to figure out what the idiomatic way was to achieve the same results in scala and like you pointed out lazy vals and by name parameters are the way to go in scala.

Comment: The last part doesn't seem to be correct. I tested the second part and if you pass doIt parameter as true the expensive function gets called every time. You can test it by passing this function def expensive = {println("I got Called"); "return value"} and then test it with (1 to 3).foreach(_ => maybeExpensiveTwice(true,expensive))

Comment: @Reza - I mean that it's only called once _per method invocation_ despite being used twice within that method.  Of course if you call the method multiple times, it will be called as many times as the method is called.  (To avoid that you need to cache it at a higher level.)

Answer (score 20):

Scala has `lazy val`s, whose initializers are not evaluated unless and until the val is used. Lazy vals may be used as method local variables.

Scala also has by-name method parameters, whose actual parameter expressions are wrapped in a thunk and that thunk is evaluated every time the formal parameter is referenced in the method body.

Together these can be used to achieve lazy evaluation semantics such as are the default in Haskell (at least in my very limited understanding of Haskell).

```
def meth(i: => Int): Something = {
  //        ^^^^^^ by-name parameter syntax
  lazy val ii = i
  // Rest of method uses ii, not i
}
```

In this method, the expression used as the actual parameter will be evaluated either zero times (if the dynamic execution path of the method body never uses `ii`) or once (if it uses `ii` one or more times).

Comment: Thanks for the info on by-name parameters and lazy vals, I'm sure they will come in handy in simplifying some of my code. As for my original question it turns out that scala allows similar redefinition of function variables as javascript so almost the same code works. All my original tests had syntax errors that were preventing me from achieving the same results as in javascript.

Comment: @davidk01 - But you don't want to do it the JavaScript way, even though you can.  There are much cleaner ways to achieve the same thing in Scala!

Comment: When using this technique, is there a way to explicitly clean up the val from outside the method? I ask myself when the val will be cleaned up by GC. The general GC behavior is clear, but with technique it can be confusing, because this method could be passed around and stored as a function. I'm in a situation, where this technique is very useful, but after a given point in execution, I would like to clean the val up, but I don't want to clean up the surrounding object. Any way to accomplish this or is this just impossible, because its a val?

Comment: Methods cannot be passed around and stored as a function. The method would have to be lifted to a Function before that's possible. As for GC behavior: a) There is no way to force references to cease to exist other than to assign `null` to the field or local variable that holds them (impossible for a `val` and there is no such thing as `lazy var`); b) There should be little reason to worry about them since there's nothing particularly special about a function (or by-name thunk) vs. any other kind of JVM instance.

Answer (score 10):

You can define a lazy val which is a function :

```
lazy val foo = {
  val d = new Date
  () => { d }
}

println(foo())
```

`foo()` will now return the same Date object each time, object which will be initialized the first time foo is called.

To explain the code a little, the first time foo() is called `{ val d = new Date; () => { d } }` is executed, d is assigned to a new date value then it evaluate the last expression `() => { d }` and assign it to the foo value. Then foo is a function with no parameters which return d.

Answer (score 6):

I think some of the responders were a little confused by the way you phrased the question. The Scala construct you want here is a simple lazy definition:

```
lazy val foo = new java.util.Date
```

The construction of the Date object will occur at most once and be deferred until the first reference to foo.

Answer (score 4):

I known nothing about Ruby, but scala has singleton object pattern also:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.r22634-b20100728020027 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_20).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> object LazyInit {                                       
     |     val msec = { println("Hi,I'm here!");   System.currentTimeMillis }
     | }
defined module LazyInit

scala> System.currentTimeMillis                                              
res0: Long = 1282728315918

scala> println(System.currentTimeMillis +" : " + LazyInit.msec)              
Hi,I'm here!
1282728319929 : 1282728319930

scala> println(System.currentTimeMillis +" : " + LazyInit.msec)
1282728322936 : 1282728319930

scala> println(System.currentTimeMillis +" : " + LazyInit.msec)
1282728324490 : 1282728319930

scala>
```

If you want to get function ,you can make it subtype of a function type:

```
scala> object LazyFun extends (() => Long) {            
     |     val msec = System.currentTimeMillis          
     |     def apply() = msec                           
     | }
defined module LazyFun

scala> System.currentTimeMillis                         
res2: Long = 1282729169918

scala> println(System.currentTimeMillis + " : " + LazyFun())
1282729190384 : 1282729190384

scala> println(System.currentTimeMillis + " : " + LazyFun())
1282729192972 : 1282729190384

scala> println(System.currentTimeMillis + " : " + LazyFun())
1282729195346 : 1282729190384
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean "lazy function" is function literal or anonymous function.

In Scala you could do things like this, very similar to the javascript code you posted.

```
val foo = () => {
    val t = new Date()
    val foo = () => {t}

    foo()
}

println ("Hello World:" + foo())
```

The main difference is that:

- You could not re-assignment the outer foo
- There is no "function" keyword, instead you use something like (s:String) => {code}
- The last statement is the return value of a block, so you don't need add "return".